# Passing a field to the sort method via a parameter via a function

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to pass a field to the sort method via a parameter but it is not working.

```
var sortBy = “deliveryDate”
db.orders.aggregate([{$match:{}}, {$sort: {sortBy: -1}}, {$limit: 10}])
```

Note: sortBy can either be orderDate or deliveryDate.

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: @ChrisJ its like you are trying to make pagination, this tool maybe can help you https://github.com/mrbontor/mongo-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
var sortBy = "deliveryDate"
db.orders.aggregate([ 
   {$sort: {[sortBy]: -1}}, 
   {$limit: 10}
])
```

`{$match:{}}` is pointless, remove it.